# Non Malicious vb.net Console app detected as virus? (FTP uploader)

Tags: vb.net, ftp, console, console-application

So I made kinda a "dropbox" type program for some of my friends computers. You place files in a specific folder, and when my console app sees a file created, it uploads it via ftp to my server. The file is then deleted from their computer. On my computer, I have another program running that checks the ftp server for new files, and download them to my computer.

Anyways, the reason I made this was mainly for learning purposes, but it also does serve a valid purpose. The problem is if they have avg installed, it detects it as a generic virus. Is there anything in my code that I can change so it doesn't seem like a virus?

The console app has a registry entry to run it at startup. I also set application type in the project settings to windows forms application so the console app basically runs hidden.

Code:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()
    watcher.Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    watcher.Filter = ""
    AddHandler watcher.Created, AddressOf OnChanged
    While True
    End While
End Sub
Private Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    'when a file is created
    Dim FilePath As String = e.FullPath
    Try
        Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("Ftp server" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
        request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)

        Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
        strz.Close()
        strz.Dispose()
        System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Try
    End Try
End Sub
End Module
```

I removed ftp info for security purposes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The console app has a registry entry to run it at startup.
>
> so the console app basically runs hidden.
>
> [watches directory and without user interaction..] it uploads it via ftp to my server

The classic detection of malware is done with signatures, but this way mainly already known malware can be detected. Thus current AV engines use behavioral analysis to detect suspicious behavior. Unfortunately, several things you do are typical for malware stealing user data too, so this probably triggers the behavioral analysis.

You are not the only one with this problem, even large companies face it and there were also cases were AV products detected critical components of windows as malware. Since you probably can not make all AV vendors to add your program to their white list the best way is probably, if there is an explicit exception done  for your program on your friends machine. How this is done depends on the AV used but I'm sure there is a way for it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So there's not much I can do to make the antivirus not detect it?

Comment: If you would be a major software developer AV companies would probably take care that they don't mark your products inadvertently as malware. But since you are not that big yet and your product actually behaves similar to some malware there is probably nothing you can do except manually flagging this software as safe on your friends computer.